# type conversion in c

Tags: c, floating-point, int, type-conversion

```
int main()
{
   int x,y;
   int z;
   char s='a';
   x=10;y=4;
   z = x/y;
   printf("%d\n",s); //97
   printf("%f",z); //some odd sequence
   return 0;

}
```

in the above piece of code the char s is automatically converted to int while printing due to the int type in control string, but in the second case the int to float conversion doesn't happen. Why so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both cases the second argument is promoted to `int`. This is how variadic functions work, and has nothing to do with the format string.

The format string is not even looked at by the compiler: it's just an argument to some function. Well, a really helpful compiler *might* know about `printf()` and *might* look at the format string, but only to warn you about mistakes you might have made. In fact, `gcc` does just that:

```
t.c:9: warning: format ‘%f’ expects type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

It is ultimately *your* responsibility to ensure that the variadic arguments match the format string. Since in the second `printf()` call they don't, the behaviour of the code is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Functions with variable number of arguments follow the rule of the *default argument promotion*. Integer promotion rules are applied on arguments of integer types and `float` arguments are converted to `double`.

```
printf("%d\n",s);
```

`s`is a char and is converted to `int`.

```
printf("%f",z);
```

`z` is already an `int` so no conversion is performed on `z`

Now the conversion specifier `f` expects a `double`  but the type of the object after the *default argument promotion* is an `int` so it is undefined behavior.

Here is what C says on arguments of library functions with variable number of arguments

> (C99, 7.4.1p1) "If an argument to a function has [...] a type (after promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of arguments, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 0):

The `char` is **not** being promoted to `int` due to the control string. The `char` is working as an int because all data that is less than 4 bytes when passed to `printf` is bumped up to 4 bytes, which is the size of an `int`, because of the cdecl calling convention of variadic functions (the point of this is so that the data that comes next will be aligned on a 4-byte boundary on the stack).

`printf` is not type-safe and has no idea what data you really pass it; it blindly reads the control string and extracts a certain number of bytes from the stack based on what sequences it finds, and interprets that set of bytes as the datatype corresponding to the control sequence. It doesn't perform any conversions, and the reason you are getting some wierd printout is because the bits of an `int` are being interpreted as the bits of a `float`.

Comment: Can't it be that `printf` fetches arguments for the `%f` specifier from floating point registers? Unrelated: you typo'ed 'weird'.

Comment: @DanielFischer no, floating point values are also passed on the stack. You can see this by looking at the source code for the `va_arg` macro.

Answer (score 0):

> due to the int type in control string

That is incorrect. It is being converted because shorter int types are promoted to `int` by the var_args process.  Int types are not converted to float types because the va/preprocessor doesn't know what formats are expected.